# Find the area between the functions

Tags: calculus

I have a homework where I have to find the area between the functions $y=x-2$ and $y=\sqrt{7-2x}$.

Computing the integral I have found $A=\frac {x^2}2-2x-\frac13 (7-2x)^{3/2}$; The upper limit is $\frac72$ and the downlimit is $2$.

After make the computing I have found $A= -0.607051$.

I think there is something wrong with the answer.

Comment: maybe this helps you if you want to write down equation in a more readable way: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: A negative area is a good sign something is wrong.

Comment: Specify the desired area accurately so that you can get the correct answer. The area under the square root function alone  is different (larger) from the area enclosed by the intersection of the 2 curves, hence, the answer will be different.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to draw a picture:

[image]

The two curves cross, so you will need to divide this into two separate integrals. They cross when $x-2=\sqrt{7-2x}$, so that $(x-2)^2 = x^2-4x+4 = 7-2x$. Solving gives $x=3$ (and $x=-1$, which you don't care about here). The integrals of the two functions are
$$\int (x-2)\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - 2x + C,\qquad
  \int \sqrt{7-2x}\,dx = -\frac{1}{3}(7-2x)^{3/2} + C$$
(note that the integral in your post above is incorrect). Therefore the enclosed area is
$$
\int_2^3 (\sqrt{7-2x}-(x-2))\,dx + \int_3^{7/2} ((x-2)-\sqrt{7-2x})\,dx,$$
which evaluates to $-\frac{13}{24} + \sqrt{3}\approx 1.19038$.

Comment: You  have found the area between the functions $y=x−2$ and $y=\sqrt{7−2x}$ and x-axis. The question has not word "and x-axis". But I understand that the problem has no solution without this words